# Using Indy to access Datasnap Rest Server method

Tags: rest, delphi, indy

Sorry if my question is obvious. I have no experience with Rest Server. I did a long search on google and stackoverflow, but I didn´t find a response to my case.
I have created DataSnap Rest Server using the Delphi Wizard with default settings in XE7.
In addition to ReverseString and EchoString default methods created by wizard, I created a new method:

```
//Server Method
function TSrvServerMetodos.SenMsgToUsers(Plataform: integer;
  Users: TJSONArray; Title, Msg: String): String;
begin
 //staff code
end;
```

My datasnap rest server is running in localhost:8080.

On client side, I am trying access this method using code with Indy:

```
procedure TfrmUntClientRest.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
const                              //TsrvServerMetodos/
  sendUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/TsrvServerMetodos/SendPushToUsers';
var
  Params: TStringList;
  idHTTP: TIDHTTP;
  SSLIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  AuthHeader,r: string;
begin
  idHTTP := TIDHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
      SslIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
      idHTTP.IOHandler := SSLIOHandler;
      Params := TStringList.Create;
      idHTTP.Request.Host := sendUrl;
      Params.Values['Plataform']:='1';
      Params.Values['Users=']:='["Luiz"]';
      Params.Values['Title']:='Tit';
      Params.Values['Msg']:='Msg';
      IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
      r:=IdHTTP.Post(sendUrl, Params);
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Send result: ' + r);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(idHTTP);
    Params.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When I click on Button to run the code above, I am getting the next error:
"First chance exception at $747F1CDA. Exception class TDBXError with message 'TsrvServerMetodos.updateSendPushToUsers method not found in the server method list'. Process DataSnapServer.exe (6236)"

My problem is:

1. My procedure is SendPushToUsers, but Rest Server is mapping to updateSendPushToUsers. Does someone could help me to solve it?
2. Is there a way to have a shortcut path to  url as http://localhost:8080/SendPushToUsers instead of http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/TsrvServerMetodos/SendPushToUsers?

Thanks is Advance, Luiz

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question: you can always use a reverse proxy (Apache HTTP, nginx) which translates URLs so that a request to the external resource

```
http://example.com/SendPushToUsers
```

will be routed to

```
http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/TsrvServerMetodos/SendPushToUsers
```

Configuration examples and docs can be found on the web, for example [here](http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC11/configure-apache-httpd-as-a-reverse-proxy-modproxy.html) and [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html).

Regarding your first question: this can be done with a reverse proxy too.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not running the Server App in a WebServer. It's a desktop standalone app.

Comment: I found the response to first question here: http://docwiki.appmethod.com/appmethod/1.13/topics/en/DataSnap_REST_Messaging_Protocol. Does someone can help with the second question? Regards, Luiz

Comment: I know this is late - but for others (me) looking at it - the link you referenced for the answer to the first part also has a hint for the answer to the second question right at the top.
It doesn't look like you can get around needing the classname but you can get rid of the first two parts.
Look at the DSContext and RESTContext properties on the WebDispatcher component.